# Resizing or removing Java JFrame headers

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a java application with a set size (it is a project creation screen for now, and I don't want this screen to be large). I'm trying to set the JFrame I use to display in such a way that I have even spacing between all elements and the top/bottom of the frame, but I don't know the size of the frame header (or what the strip at the top of the frame is called, I don't know what else to call it). Does anyone know what the height of the header is? Is there a way to resize or remove it outright? I'd like to have more control over what I can do with the frame. Thanks

The header I would like to know about:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6adI.png]

Comment: You don’t want the title bar - you could try and undecorsted window or a JDialog which if I recall correctly it doesn’t have a resize min/max button

Comment: *I have even spacing between all elements and the top/bottom of the frame,* - this is done by using layout managers. After all components are added to the frame you then `pack()` the frame and you can then use `setResizable(false)` on the frame to prevent the user from resizing the frame. You should NOT attempt to calculate sizes manually. The size can be different depending on the OS you are using.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. For example a `GridBagLayout` will automatically center the panel horizontally and vertically inside the frame.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the title bar, set `frame.setUndecorated(true);`. This will remove all decorations for the JFrame.

Full example:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Example {

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Some title");
        frame.add(new JLabel("test"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Example ex = new Example();
            }
        });
    }

}
```